# Drop Down Menu Not Working in Any IE Inside Of Ebay Listing

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

Hey Everyone hope all good. Ok I have this issue and am seeking some guidance.

I have a drop down navigation menu for one of my eBay listings. This Drop down menu works fine in all other browsers except any IE browsers. I have added a live example on my eBay sandbox account for you to look at.

http://cgi.sandbox.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=110126145012#ht_500wt_1156

I am using the same drop down menu on the store and it works on all browsers including ie9,ie8,ie7, so for some reason as soon as i put it inside of the listing everything stops working in ie. The only thing i can think of is that there is something blocking it, or some code that eBay has that is overwriting it some how. I thought i would get someone else to have a look and see if they notice anything or have had experience in this issue. Here is the code i am using

HTML

```
<div id="menu-wrap">
<div class="menu">
<ul>

<li><a class="home" href="#"></a></li>

<li><a href="#">Name Of Link</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Newborn</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link7</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link8</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

<li><a href="#">Socks/Tights</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Link6</a></li>
</ul>
</li>

</ul>
</div><!-- END menu -->
</div><!-- END menu-wrap -->
```

CSS

```
.menu{float:left; width:902px;margin:5px 0px 0px 125px;}
.menu ul{margin:0; padding:0; float:left; list-style:none;}
.menu ul li{position:relative;float:left;margin: 0px; padding: 0px;}
.menu ul li a{display:block;height:63px; padding: 0px 13px 0px 13px; font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 27px; font-weight: normal; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; margin: 0px 2px 0px 0px; background:url(../images/menu-arrow-hover.png) no-repeat right 25px;line-height: 52px;}
.menu ul li a.home {margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; background-image:none;}
.menu ul li a.home img { border:0px;}
.menu ul li a.home:hover {margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px; background:none;}
.menu ul:hover li.active a{text-decoration:none;}   
.menu ul li.active > a, .menu ul li:hover > a, .menu ul li.active:hover a{text-decoration:none; background: #6bbed1 url(../images/menu-sub-hover.png) no-repeat 25px bottom; }
.menu ul li a:active, .menu ul li.active a:active{color:#CCC;}
.menu ul ul{position:absolute;visibility:hidden;opacity:0;border: 10px solid #fff;background: #f3f3f3;min-width: 15em;padding: 20px 0 8px;-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);-moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);z-index: 9999;}
.menu ul li:hover > ul{visibility:visible;opacity:1;}
.menu ul ul li{cursor:pointer; text-align:left;}
.menu ul ul li a{width:134px; height:31px;padding-right:0; color: #434343;font-size: 18px; line-height:32px;text-transform:none;display: block;padding: 0 0 3px 7px;}
.menu ul ul li span{position:absolute;top:0;right:10px;font-size:16px;}
.menu ul ul li:hover > a{background:#f3f3f3; color:#83d14f;}
.menu ul ul li a:active{color:#CCC;}
.menu ul ul ul{top:-1px;left:100%;padding:0;}
.menu input#dropdown, .menu label{display:none;position:absolute;top:5px;right:14px;width:46px;height:35px;}
.menu input#dropdown{opacity:0;}
.menu label{background:#222 url(../images/list_icon.png) no-repeat center;webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;}
.menu label:hover{cursor:pointer;}
.menu input#dropdown:checked ~ label{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 28px #2A2A2A, inset 0 0 6px #1A1A1A;-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 28px #2A2A2A, inset 0 0 6px #1A1A1A;box-shadow:inset 0 0 28px #2A2A2A, inset 0 0 6px #1A1A1A;}
.menu input#dropdown:checked ~ ul{display:block;}   
.menu p{display:none;position:absolute;top:12px;left:14px;margin:0;font:19px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color:#9E9E9E;}
```

Any Help would be much appreciated

Thanks for your time

Ali

Answer (score 0):

Your using opacity to hide and show the nested  tags. Ie 8 and below I believe does not support opacity or rgba. You can fix this by doing display none to hide and display block to show.

I will make a fiddle when I am home to show you, I am currently using my iphone :/.

Here is a fiddle I have made from a previous question until I get home.

[JSFIDDLE][1]

http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/XvQRH/[1]